# Edit php string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a string that makes a function from my order status. I wan´t to have it to trigger with 2 order status´
Is that posible?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__redshop_orders where order_payment_status ='Paid' and order_status = 'RD2'";
```

So insted of just trigger with status RD2 it should trigger with RD1+RD2

Plus - I wan´t to remove the order_payment_status function, so it only triggers for order status.

How will the string look like after editting?
Thank you.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/

Comment: It's about PHP, or about SQL? Because the name suggest that the question is about how to edit a string in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__redshop_orders WHERE order_status = 'RD1' OR order_status = 'RD2'";
```

You should try to learn MySQL, a simple google search would give you plenty of example and tutorials.

EDIT:

I made some tests since I posted my answer, and the benchmarks show that a much faster solution would be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__redshop_orders WHERE order_status IN ('RD1', 'RD2')";
```

Comment: Good call on using IN().

Comment: I havent been able to test it in the function yet. But this should work for me. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__redshop_orders WHERE order_status IN ('RD1', 'RD2')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__redshop_orders    where   order_status IN('RD1','RD2')";
```

//You want this